# Is is possible to pipe the output of a command from a server to a local machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have a series of functionally identical servers provided by my school that run various OS and hardware configurations. For the most part, I can use 5 of these interchangeably. Unfortunately, other students tend to bunch up on some machines and It's a pain to find one that isn't bogged down.

What I want to is ssh into a machine, run the command:

```
w | wc -l
```

to get a rough estimate of the load on that server, and use that information to select the least impacted one. A sort of client-side load balancer.

Is there a way to do this or achieve the same result?

Comment: Aren't you asking about `ssh hostname w | wc -l`? Or `for hostname in hostA hostB hostC hostD; do ssh $hostname w | wc -l; done`?

Comment: huh, I guess I've never seen it used that way before. Thanks.

Comment: If you have `ruptime`, try that. The actual load is probably a better metric than the number of users; `ssh host uptime` if you don't have `ruptime`. See the manual for what the numbers mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put this on your `.bashrc` file

```
function choose_host(){
hosts="host1 ... hostn"
for host in $hosts
do
  echo $(ssh $host 'w|wc -l') $host
done | sort | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
}

function ssh_host(){
  ssh $(choose_host)
}
```

`choose_host` should give you the one you're looking for. This is absolutely overkill but i was feeling playful :D
`sort` will order the output according to the result of `w|wc -l`, then `head -1` gets the first line and `awk` will just print the hostname !
You can call `ssh_host` and should log you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdsh) command from your desktop which run the specified command on the set of machines you specified and return the results. This way you can find out the one which is least loaded. This will avoid you doing `ssh` to every single machine and run the `w | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See e.g.:

```
ssh me@host "ls /etc | sort" | wc -l
```

The part inside `""` is done remotely. The part afterwards is local.